# Android applications with SQLite: is sqllite data stored locally on the phone only?

Tags: android, sqlite

... or can I acess it remotely? If yes, where/how?

To illustrate my question with an example:
If I want to implement a login function and an user creates an account: will his login information only be stored on his phone? (So he can only login on his phone on nowhere else?) Or is it stored somewhere else?

I'm quite confused at the moment and wasn't able to find good ressources zu answer my question (maybe someone knows a good tutorial?)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly 3 ways to store data in `android`:

1. With the [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), you can save data *locally*. Its limit is that when you close your app the data are deleted.
2. With [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) the limit of the *shared preferences* is overcome. You can save data into a binary file stored *locally* in your phone. For use it you have to write some specific java code and inside it write in SQL sintax. It is used for example to keep the highest score in single player game, or simply to let the app remember description, text, user inputs.
3. With [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=en) you can save data in a not local way, data are stored in a *server*. You can use it for example for develop a social, a game that need to share data with more users, when you have a multiuser application.

   [This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#pref)  is a *data file storage overview*, it could be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

For login data it's better to use share preference instead of SQLite. If you use SQLite or Room or share preference, data are saved locally and you can't access them remotely.

Comment: Okay thank you! And when using shared preferences the user could also login on another device?

Comment: Surely not. As I said you share preference is local @pony